# Creating daemon process to run a function in the background without using threading

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

**TL;DR**

I want to create something similar to `daemon` using `threading`. I use a Windows machine. So, `python-daemon` does not work on my system.

**Problem**

I am developing an application that uses `threading` to generate a tone when an event is detected. In the app, I am streaming some data, processing, and detecting certain events. When an event is detected, a tone is generated. I am creating a `thread` with `daemon = True`, and calling a tone generation function `generate_tone`. However, I don't think I need to generate multiple threads to run this task.

Please note that the code below is a sub-module invoked by another `thread` running in the background. The background thread is streaming the data from the sensors. In the code below, the `generate_tone` function generates a sinusoid tone of 0.2 seconds. If I call this function without using threads, it will take 0.2 seconds of current thread, thereby introducing 0.2 seconds delay. However, I don't want this to happen. I also don't want to use `time.sleep(0.2)` after calling the thread, i.e., after `thread.start()` because doing this will again introduce 0.2 seconds in the loop.

Also, note that the code below will not generate any sound because a new thread is called before the execution of previous thread. However, it will print all the threads when `threading.enumerate()` is called.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import math
import threading

def play_tone(stream, frequency=440, length=1, rate=44100):
    chunks = []
    chunks.append(sine(frequency, length, rate))

    chunk = np.concatenate(chunks) * 0.25

    stream.write(chunk.astype(np.float32).tostring())

def generate_tone():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1, rate=44100, output=1)

    play_tone(stream,length=0.20)
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

def sine(frequency, length, rate):
    length = int(length * rate)
    factor = float(frequency) * (math.pi * 2) / rate
    return np.sin(np.arange(length) * factor)

def detect_event():
    T = 0.1
    iter = 0
    iter_max = 10

    while iter < iter_max:
        # some random vector x
        x = np.random.rand(10,)
        # check if any element of x is greater than T
        if len(x[ np.where( x >= T ) ]) != 0:
            beep_thread = threading.Thread(target=generate_tone,args=(),daemon=True)
            beep_thread.start()
            print(threading.enumerate())

        iter = iter + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    detect_event()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: There are definitely some indentation issues in the first few lines.

Comment: I want to invoke the `generate_tone()` function without introducing any delays in the `while` loop.

Comment: Fixed indentation issues.

Comment: Maybe my title is a bit misleading. I want to create a daemon process such that the `generate_tone` function does not introduce any delay in the `while` loop.

Comment: @Maxton. You should edit the main post and its title to reflect what you mean. People shouldn't have to look through the comments to understand your question.

Comment: I'm removing my close vote since you've been quite responsive and understanding. I'm not sure what your reasoning behind "I don't think I need to generate multiple threads to run this task."

Comment: @MadPhysicist I modified the title. Thanks again for your comments. If you run the code, you will see what my problem is. I just want to invoke the `generate_tone` function without introducing any delay in the `while` loop.

Comment: The problem is that Python does not normally support true multithreading where both threads are actively doing something. Instead of using threading, use multiprocessing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It works! Is there a limit on the number of processes that I can create?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is it possible to use `Event` from `multiprocessing` generate the beep tones?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, but I'll look into it on Monday if you'd like. I'm quite familiar with threading, but not with the Python implementation of multiprocessing. I'll figure it out with a little research though.